# Multiple Passport LocalStrategies

Tags: node.js

we are developing an e-commerce website in that admin and user table are there here we are authenticating the admin and user if he is admin only then he can access the admin site an he can utilise the admin benefits if not he cannot login to the admin site

for that our routing code is

```
function ensureAdmin(req, res, next){
    console.log("reached :");
    if(req.isAuthenticated()){

      if (req.admin.role == 'admin')
      {

        return next();
      }
      else {
        req.logout();
        res.redirect('/admin');
       }

    }
    else {

        res.redirect('/admin');
    }
}

router.post('/admin/login', passport.authenticate('admin', {successRedirect:'/admin/dashboard',failureRedirect:'/admin',failureFlash: true}), function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('/admin/dashboard');
});
```

In the above code the authentication `if(req.isAuthenticated)(){` that condition it self not working the admin and user collections are different tables 
now what can i do

Answer (score 6):

You can do it by having 2 different LocalStrategies to authenticate user and admin differently (in your case from different tables).

Something like :

```
passport.use('user', new LocalStrategy(  //'user' strategy
  function(username, password, done) {
    User.findOne(/* ... */)
  }
));

passport.use('admin', new LocalStrategy( //'admin' strategy
  function(username, password, done) {
    Admin.findOne(/* ... */)
  }
));

   //user login, uses the 'user' strategy
      app.post('/user/login',
        passport.authenticate('user', { successRedirect: '/user/home', failureRedirect: '/user/login' }));


  //Admin login, uses the admin strategy
    app.post('/admin/login',  
      passport.authenticate('admin', { successRedirect: '/admin/dashboard', failureRedirect: '/admin/login' }));
```